# Size of Reactjs app growing to hundred Megabytes

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I build a software by reactjs and deployed to heroku.
The problem here is deployment package (to heroku) seems too big !!!

Build log from heroku, it is 164M !?
[image]

Size of component in node_modules:
[image]

I already delete "node_modules" folder, reinstall all package by npm i --production, but there's no change.

Although only several functions in a big library is needed/used. But seems whole  package are loaded into the app. That will increasing deployment package.
I think it should have the way to pack only needed functions to deployment ?

Comment: can you share your package.json? `npm i --production` just removes your `devDependencies` so you should only have modules needed at runtime added as `dependencies`

Comment: Does the large size cause any problems? 164MB actually isn't that bad for a server side app. Heroku does a lot of caching of dependencies, so you may be trying to solve a non issue here. Also, not that this is _not_ the side of the javascript bundle that user needs to download when they visit your website.

Comment: Actually first-time page load take  ~30 seconds. Is it normal ? 
I think it is because of large size -> client browser should download (almost) all of them before display/run ?